# scipy.optimze.fmin_bfgs returns different results for same objective function

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm using scipy for minimizing some functions but run into a weird issue. The problem is that if I run scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs several times with the same objective function and initial point, it returns different results each time.

Here is my code:

```
# objective function (a bit long, I know)
>>> def obj_fun(x):
...     x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3 = x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]
...     return -(x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y1 - y3) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) ** 2.0 + 10240.0 * ((x1 ** 2.0 + 2.0 * x1 * y1 + 3.0
* y1 ** 2.0 - 1.0) ** 2.0 + (x2 ** 2.0 + 3.0 * x2 * y2 + 2.0 * y2 ** 2.0 - 3.0) ** 2.0 + (x3 ** 2.0 + 1.3 * x3 * y3 + 4.
0 * y3 ** 2.0 - 7.0) ** 2.0)
```

And how I call `fmin_bfgs`:

```
>>> fmin_bfgs(obj_fun, np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: -234096226752563985252352.000000
         Iterations: 342
         Function evaluations: 4596
         Gradient evaluations: 475
array([ -6.96051555e+04,  -3.83874412e+06,   5.37631361e+04,
         3.48506449e+04,   3.83874414e+06,  -1.94246588e+04,
         6.00000000e+00])
>>> fmin_bfgs(obj_fun, np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]))
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: -22936558246668045123584.000000
         Iterations: 553
         Function evaluations: 7218
         Gradient evaluations: 747
array([ -3.91291135e+04,  -2.14765204e+06,   3.03606753e+04,
         1.95065952e+04,   2.14765197e+06,  -1.08606776e+04,
         6.00000000e+00])
```

Note that I'm calling `fmin_bfgs` with the exact same objective function and initial point but it's simply returning different results.

What could this be? How could I achieve the desired behavior?

### Edit:

I just tested this same code in a computer with an `AMD A10-5750M` processor and it worked!! I also tested it in an `Intel Core2 Duo U9400` computer and it didn't!! My own computer has an `Intel Core i3-2330M` and of course it doesn't work.
The 3 computers are running on Windows 8.1 and have the same versions of python, numpy and scipy installed (2.7, 1.7.1 and 0.11.0 respectively).

I have no idea if this matters but I'm going crazy already.

Comment: Strange, I get the exact the  same repeated output on each run including iterations. What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python v2.7, numpy v1.6.2 and scipy v0.11.0. I had that code integrated into a larger application and thinking I could be breaking something in the way, I just tested it in the console, with the same wrong results :(

Comment: I am using numpy=='1.8.1' and scipy=='0.13.3' with python2.7. Maybe that is the reason? Try updating with pip. Your numpy version is a couple of years old.

Comment: The function value is ridiculously large.  Perhaps you'll get consistent results if you scale the problem?

Comment: @RobFalck: My objective function is really just `-(x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y1 - y3) + x3 * (y1 - y2)) ** 2.0`, the rest is the result of applying a quadratic penalization given some constrains.

Comment: Are you sure your minus in front is correct? It looks strange to me to find the maximum of a quadratic function.  If I multiply the entire objective function by `1e-8`, I get nice looking numbers. The scale really looks screwed up that fmin_bfgs is not able to calculate meaningful or numerically precise things. (my guess)

Comment: @user333700: My problem is actually to maximize [this](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn9808.png) function. In order to do that I changed modulus by square and changed the sign, yielding that new objective function to minimize.

Comment: I think @RobFalck nailed it. [bfgs works by approximating the Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) and invokes matrix inversions. It is likely that your matrix has a [large condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) that leads the algorithm astray. Can you reduce the penalty terms and see if you get stability?

Comment: @Ioannis: It's quite possible that my matrix is ill-conditioned, but wouldn't it have the same condition number every time? I mean, after all I'm using the same function and initial guess in each call, so the condition number is always the same, am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed the condition number is a property of the matrix. However, a large condition number implies that the matrix inversion is prone to numerical errors. This, coupled with round-off errors common in every floating point arithmetic system can lead to the results you are getting..